# How to connect to a Remote Windows Server via internet without using Static IP?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-access, dns-hosting

How to connect to a Remote Windows Server via internet without using Static IP?
I have a **Windows Server 2008 R2** and i want to make it accessible to my customers so they can `work on my server through sessions` which they can access from anywhere in the entire world via internet.

### Common thought solution

You might say that purchase a static IP for it so you will be able to access it anywhere in the entire world.

### Bottleneck

I live in **India** and the only available broadband network near my location is **Airtel** or **BSNL**.

1. I already have already **purchased a nice plan from Airtel** which serves us well until the Internet link is dropped from the ISP side for hours which happens once in a month. 
   As an IT person we know that the **server needs to have 24/7 uptime** to make itself useful for the customers and if the internet link keeps dropping for hours then it is a major setback.
2. **BSNL** is prone to have frequent internet link drops and is slower than Airtel and even costs double in comparison to my current Airtel Plan, so it is out of the picture.
3. **Private ISP** don't have their internet lines stretched out to our office so that is also out of the picture.
4. **Lease Lines** are dedicated line which might solve the problem but it is expensive as hell and it is still bound to have internet link drop problem (which would probably be less than the normal broadband connection as it is dedicated).
5. **Internet Dongle** - I thought of using multiple ISP dongle to maximize the uptime of the server BUT that again wasn't possible because i don't know a way through which the customer can connect to the server because there is no **PUBLIC IP** or anything that the customer can use it to access the remote server.
6. I was suggested by someone to do the following but i have no idea how to do it. If someone can show me how to do it or refer to an article related to it, it would be much appreciated.

> use **dynamic dns service** that you set up on your server, and
> connect to your server using a host name instead of its IP address.
> However, this question is not a programming question, and therefore
> offtopic here – nos

### Back to the Main Question

Are there any other ways that i might have missed through which i can make my server readily available to my end customers **without investing a lot and using a Static IP**.

Comment: This is the complete guide how you can achieve it https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/using-remote-desktop-with-no-ip/

Answer (score 2):

You can *try* to use a dynamic DNS service and connect your server via different means to the internet and then register the current IP address with the DynDNS service. However, in many cases that might fail. As an example, using a internet dongle to connect to a mobile provider will almost certainly fail because they are setup in a way that prevents the use for a server (they are meant only for clients).

Your real solution is to NOT host your server yourself. Instead, put it into a colocation data centre or use a cloud service like AWS to provision a virtual machine instead of the physical one.